# Complex async flow that failed to execute as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I've been trying for hours yet couldn't get the correct flow. I'll share the code first and explanation comes later.

```
jobSearch();

const jobSearch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => { 
  
  console.log('DEBUG::step 1:');

  if (!refreshToken()) {
    console.log('DEBUG::step 6:');
    //.......
    //Call function to print step 8, step 9

  } else {
    console.log('DEBUG::step 7:');
    //Perform other operation
  }
}
```

Basically, `refreshToken()` is a method that is to decode jwt to check for expiry, and if expired, call REST to retrieve a new token, so there is a network request above, and the function `refreshToken` will return a Boolean to indicate the whole refresh token flow is success or fail.

```
const refreshToken = async () => {
  console.log('DEBUG::step 2:');
  let valid = true;

  if (!validateAccessToken()) { //<==just a flow to decode jwt, no async flow
    console.log('DEBUG::step 4:');
    
    // Configure retry operation
    const operation = retry.operation({
      retries: MAX_RETRIES_USER_LOGIN,
      factor: 1,
      minTimeout: INTERVAL_RETRY_USER_LOGIN,
      maxTimeout: INTERVAL_RETRY_USER_LOGIN
    });

    // Configure HTTP request
    const ax = axios.create({
      timeout: TIMEOUT_CONNECT,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      cancelToken: cancelTokenSourceJobSearch.token
    });

    console.log('DEBUG::hihi0:');
    await operation.attempt(() => {
      ax.post(urljoin(API_BASE_URL, API_ENDPOINT_TOKEN_REFRESH), {
        data: {
          refresh_token: global.setting.refresh_token
        }
      })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        valid = true;
        console.log('DEBUG::hihi1:');
        //SUCCESS!
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('DEBUG::hihi3:');
        
        // Log error to console
        console.log(err);

        if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
          valid = false;
          return;
        } else if (operation.retry(err)) {
          valid = false;
          return;
        }
      });
      return valid;
    });
  } else {
    console.log('DEBUG::step 5:');
    return valid;
  }
};
```

And below is the printed log

> DEBUG::step 1:
>
> DEBUG::step 2:
>
> DEBUG::step 3:
>
> DEBUG::step 4:
>
> DEBUG::hihi0:
>
> DEBUG::step 7:
>
> DEBUG::hihi1:

- How come `Step 7` printed before `hihi1`? I've already made it `async await`.
- `step 6` was not printed so refreshToken operation was success
- `hihi3` was not printed so no exception too

Any helps would be very much appreciated!

**UPDATES!**

As commented by @CertainPerformance and @briosheje: I've updated to below:

```
jobSearch();

const jobSearch = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => { //<==HERE

  console.log('DEBUG::step 1:');

  const shouldRefreshToken = await refreshToken();//<==HERE
  if (!shouldRefreshToken) {//<===HERE
    console.log('DEBUG::step 6:');
    //.......
    //Call function to print step 8, step 9

  } else {
    console.log('DEBUG::step 7:');
    //Perform other operation
  }
}
```

And then the flow change to become getting exception as below:

> DEBUG::step 1:
>
> DEBUG::step 2:
>
> DEBUG::step 3:
>
> DEBUG::step 4:
>
> DEBUG::hihi0:
>
> DEBUG::step 6:
>
> DEBUG::hihi1:

Comment: `refreshToken` is `async`, so you forgot to `await refreshToken()` at the very beginning. (or call `.then` on it to check its value. `refreshToken()`, returning a `Promise`, will *always* be truthy)

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I've just updated it according to what you've said but now the log printed differently. From `step1` to `hihi0`, but instead of `step7`, it printed `step 6`, `hihi1`

Comment: @Isaac where are step 8 and 9?

Comment: @briosheje, sorry for missing that out as it's not important, i've removed from my comment. And added into question if that anyhow related but i doubted so

Comment: `ax.post()...` has a flow of its own that is not part of the main flow. Sticking `await` in front of `operation.attempt()` has no effect. You can try `return ax.post()...` but the success of that depends on what `operation.attempt()` returns, which I don't know.

Comment: Is `operation.attempt()` documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!refreshToken()) {
     ^------ this is async.. Which returns a Promise<boolean>, which is always truthy.
```

(as stated here):

```
const refreshToken = async () // and some other stuff.
```

Hence, since it's marked as `async`, it will always return a `Promise`, which always leads to a truthy value.

Since it's asyncronous, you should keep the promise response and evaluate it instead:

```
console.log('DEBUG::step 1:');
// Store here the value of refreshToken
const shouldRefreshToken = await refreshToken();

if (!shouldRefreshToken) {
//  ^--- Syncronous flow here.
  console.log('DEBUG::step 6:');
  //.......

} else {
  console.log('DEBUG::step 7:');
  //Perform other operation
}
```

Other than that, the order inside the `refreshToken` method depends on the methods you're using inside it instead. If, for some reason, you are expecting `console.log('DEBUG::hihi3:');` to be called, check the axios documentation or whatever it is meant to be.
The main issue, is any case, is that you were using a `Promise` inside an if statement, which would always lead to the if statement skip.

Comment: I've updated my question and attempted your solution but failed too

Comment: `console.log('DEBUG::hihi3:');` will only be printed if the network request failed, so I was not expecting it. Putting it there just to show that our request doesnt failed